# Tring to call a local database variable and the app stop working

Tags: java, android, database, variables, android-alertdialog

My app stop working if i call a variable from the local database. I've use a ALertDialog with strings(that aloud me to translate it) and i try to call variables from my local DB.

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity
{
    private BdLocal bdl = new BdLocal(); //DB
    public static final int TAMANHOAREAFUMACA = 100;
    public static final int QUALIDADEJPEG = 100; 

    PreviewCamera mPreview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog dialog;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.afericao_instrucao) +
                String.valueOf(bdl.getLauTempo()) + //this variable make my app stop woking
                getResources().getString(R.string.fotos) +
                String.valueOf(bdl.getQntFotos()) + //this variable make my app stop woking
                getResources().getString(R.string.segundos));

        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
        dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
    }
```

I already have used some other codes, but always make my app stop working.

Solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is extremely hard to debug without the stack trace and the BdLocal code. However you can't add a dialog before the setContentView. Consider moving all of that code to the onResume method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
  super.onResume();
  AlertDialog dialog;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.afericao_instrucao) +
                String.valueOf(bdl.getLauTempo()) + //this variable make my app stop woking
                getResources().getString(R.string.fotos) +
                String.valueOf(bdl.getQntFotos()) + //this variable make my app stop woking
                getResources().getString(R.string.segundos));

        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
        dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
}
```

You can't really create dialogs if the activity isn't added to the window yet.